# Web (ASP.NET Core MVC) + Mobile (Xamarin.Android)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, cross-platform

I'm trying to build an application which will have a Web (ASP.NET Core MVC) and Mobile (Xamarin.Android) but I faced some questions as I started to work about the architecture of application.

My start was with the web version by splitting my application into 3 projects:

- MyApplication.Data
- MyApplication.Entities
- MyApplication.Web

My questions are about where I should keep some parts of my code:

- the Repositories and IRepositories in the .Data project or in a separated project, let say MyApplication.Services?
- the ViewModels in the .Data project, in the .Entities project or in the .Web project?

Is there anything else I should consider?
What are the best practices?

I would appreciate all your advices 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Base on your description, all of your issues are related to the ASP.NET Core MVC, you do not expound what is your issue about Xamarin.Android.

Comment: I thought that it would be good to know what other projects I am planning to attach with ASP.NET Core MVC which is Xamarin.Android

Comment: Ok, If no issues are related to `Xamarin.Android`, delete the `Xamarin.Android` tag may be better.